# AWS Amplify Auth - get session without refreshing token (federated sign in via SAML provider)

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-amplify

In our webapplication the users are signed in using Amplify/Cognito's `Auth.federatedSignIn()` based on a SAML identity provider.
The related OAuth flow is configured as `Authorization code grant`.

Is it possible to check whether a user has a "valid" session **WITHOUT** refreshing the identity- and accesstoken?
With valid session I mean that identity- and access-token did not already expire.
I have tested these two methods - both are refreshing the tokens (as long as the refresh token is valid):

- `Auth.currentSession()`
- `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`

Thanks for your support!